# Parse string in Java

Tags: java, string, parsing

I have a string in below format

```
// JCSDL_MASTER b04591342ee71a2baa468d9d2a340ec8 AND
// JCSDL_VERSION 1.0
// JCSDL_START 0980a5f2ef935c4ed153bf975879eac0 twitter.text,contains_any,27-52
twitter.text contains_any "obama, santorum, gingrich, romney, ronpaul, ron paul"
// JCSDL_END
AND
// JCSDL_START f7c18a6fedd90c6b4d77acc14a3a8e5c interaction.type,in,21-29
interaction.type in "twitter,facebook,digg,youtube"
// JCSDL_END
// JCSDL_MASTER_END
```

I suppose it include newline character at the end, i need to just get only those line which is not being started by // how to get only those lines?

Comment: Loop trough the file line by line, only work with those that don't start with '//'.

Comment: it's not in a file it's  simple string variable

Comment: I see. Well this is just the output: I assume your string has the characters `\n` inside of it? Split your string on that character and then check if it starts with `//`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty simply, just split up the string into individual lines (note: `\n` is an escape character for a line break), then only use each line if it does not start with `//`

```
String[] lines = string.split("\\n");

for (String line : lines)
{
  if (!line.startsWith("//"))
  {
    //use the line and do your thing
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Scanner.nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) to read each line and then Ignore the ones which starts with `//` like following:

```
    String str = "hi \n//this is kuleep\nthis is a test class";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(str);
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        if(!line.startsWith("//"))
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

Comment: come-on, how about some code that is proper

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was in hurry to write the answer. Here is the proper code.

Comment: Can the DOWNVOTER please explain what's wrong with this code. I have added complete code here now, and tested that it works.

Comment: I originally down-voted you as per my original comment.  Still compared with Luke's answer, I feel that instantiating a scanner for this is overboard.